# I want to replace NULL values by AVG in PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, mean, isnull

**Here is my Code :**

```
    claims = LOAD 'Darshan/automobile_insurance_claims.csv' USING  PigStorage(',') AS (claim_id:chararray, policy_master_id:chararray, registration_no:chararray, engine_no:chararray, chassis_no:chararray, customer_id:int, Col6:int,first_name:chararray, last_name:chararray,street:chararray,address:chararray,    city:chararray, zip:long,gender:chararray, claim_date:chararray, garage_city:chararray, bill_no:long, claim_amount:double, garage_name:chararray,claim_status:chararray);  

    grp_all = group claims all; 

    avg = foreach  grp_all generate AVG(claims.Col6); 
    grp = group claims by claim_id;  

    m = foreach grp generate group, ((Col6 IS NULL) ? avg : Col6);
```

**Results:** dump avg;  #33.45

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------***Showing following error while replacing NULL values in Col6(i.e. Age):*** 
        Caused by:
 Invalid scalar projection: avg : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a s
calar
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.var_expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:10947)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:10164)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.bin_expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:11992)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.projectable_expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:11104)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.var_expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:10815)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:10164)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.flatten_generated_item(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:7493)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.generate_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:17595)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_plan(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15987)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15854)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1933)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
        ... 17 more
2016-08-08 05:51:07,297 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
 Invalid scalar projection: avg : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a s
calar .

#### Line 11 is: m = foreach grp generate group, ((Col6 IS NULL) ? avg : Col6);

Comment: m = foreach grp generate group, ((claims.Col6 IS NULL) ? avg.$0 : claims.Col6);

Comment: please provide sample data set..

Comment: @ankur automobile_insurance_claims.csv : https://github.com/pradeep-pasupuleti/pig-design-patterns/blob/master/Chapter4/datasets/data_validation/automobile_insurance_claims.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the Final Code for my query:**

```
claims = LOAD 'Darshan/automobile_insurance_claims.csv' USING  PigStorage(',') AS 
         (claim_id:chararray, policy_master_id:chararray, registration_no:chararray, 
         engine_no:chararray, chassis_no:chararray, customer_id:int, Col6:int,
         first_name:chararray, last_name:chararray,street:chararray,address:chararray,
         city:chararray, zip:long,gender:chararray, claim_date:chararray,
         garage_city:chararray, bill_no:long, claim_amount:double,
         garage_name:chararray,claim_status:chararray);  

grp_all = group claims all; 
avg = foreach  grp_all generate AVG(claims.Col6); 
grp = group claims by claim_id; 

result = foreach grp { 
             val = foreach claims generate ((Col6 IS NULL) ? avg.$0 : Col6);
             generate group, val; 
         };
```

Here is the link to dataset [automobile_insurance_claims.csv](https://github.com/pradeep-pasupuleti/pig-design-patterns/blob/master/Chapter4/datasets/data_validation/automobile_insurance_claims.csv)

Answer (score 1):

Darshan, this doesn't look like logic issue which you are exactly trying. You can replace **NULLs** by **AVG** but here the issue is **projection** of a column.

To solve this please revisit your code once again and you may find that AVG is in different relation and you are accessing it from different relation.

In your code "avg" is a relation not a column, If I'm getting it correctly, After your first group statement where you are generating **AVG**, generate other columns as well and that's how you will have **avg** and **col6** in same relation.

1. Load your data
2. Group your data as per your need
3. Calculate AVG and generate other columns

If you want you can apply this replace logic in same FOREACH.

Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because avg is a relation and you need to use a column in the relation avg.Correct your last PIG statement to refer to the first column in the relation avg,like this

```
m = foreach grp generate group, ((claims.Col6 IS NULL) ? (double)avg.$0 : claims.Col6);
```

Alternatively you can name the column and refer to it as well,like this

```
avg = foreach  grp_all generate AVG(claims.Col6) AS AVG_Col6; 
grp = group claims by claim_id;  
m = foreach grp generate group, ((claims.Col6 IS NULL) ? (double)avg.AVG_Col6 : claims.Col6);
```

Comment: Yeah that's the perfect solution for what i was looking. But getting another ERROR : Unsupported input type for BinCond: left hand side: double; right hand side: bag .......It is taking claims.Col6 as Bag

Comment: Try casting avg.AVG_Col6 like this, I suspect it is AVG_Col6 and not claims.Col6 since claims.Col6 is a field and its type is int. m = foreach grp generate group, ((claims.Col6 IS NULL) ? (double)avg.AVG_Col6 : claims.Col6); I've edited the answer

Comment: avg.Col6 or avg.AVG_Col6 is ok.......It is taking claims.Col6 as BAG. I have to change this claims.Col6 into Double. ( ERROR : Unsupported input type for BinCond: left hand side: double; right hand side: bag)

Comment: can't you cast it,just like avg_col6?

Comment: Nope. It is showing error. Can't cast from Bag to Double.

Comment: can you describe grp?After grouping write DESRCIBE grp; and post the output?

Comment: Hey thanks for all your help. It actually needs to FLATTEN. Got another way to do it. I'm posting the whole solution......